# Protection Devices in DC ciruits

Tags: dc, fuses, circuit-breaker, panel

I am putting together a design for a custom Electrical panel. The panel consists of mainly DC powered components (Sensors, Controllers). Components are to be mechanically positioned using a DIN rail.

Operating voltage of the DC circuit is 24V, and components in the circuit have maximum current ratings ranging from 1A to 3A

Adequate and proper protection is a major requirement in this project.
Digging around for circuit breakers, i realized that the more common AC circuit breakers out there (In my geographic location) are not recommended to be used in DC circuits.

Further digging also revealed that these DC Circuit breakers are about 2 to 3 times the cost of their AC counterparts which is bummer as this has affected my projected costing.

Alternatives i read about include the use of fuses. This has its advantages and disadvantages too.

My question is, in my scenario what is the industry recommended way of providing protection in DC circuits.

Comment: DC breakers are more expensive as it is harder to 'break' a DC current than an AC current. (In case of e.g. arcing the arc will stop when the current is zero, which will be the case for an AC current as it crosses 0A each time when it changes polarity).

Comment: Is all the 24V inside the panel, or does some power remote sensors?

Comment: 1A to 3A is very small current, you can use electronic protection. https://shop.osd-schenck.de/epages/es549793.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/es549793/Products/6EP1961-2BA11

Comment: Maybe if you watch the video, you will get the basic idea about the purpose (I think you are looking exactly for some similar solution) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pEPTliTL8M

Comment: @Mattman944 Sensors are outside of the panel but have their power and communication cables routed into the panel

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Thanks for this. Looks live a viable product but a bit on the high side in terms of price. Will have been okay if it included a voltage transformer (ie 230V AC - 24V DC). That will have saved me the extra cost of buying a stand alone Power supply. Nevertheless, its a practical part and will come in handy one day.

Comment: The most important thing to protect against is a fire. Wires outside of the panel are more of a concern. If a 24V wire outside the panel shorts to ground, you should have some type of protection. If the wires will handle the short circuit current of the 24V power supply, that may be sufficient. Else, you want something that will interrupt the power, an electronic protection like Marko recommended, or a fuse.

Comment: Sure the industrial components are expensive. You can use a fuse instead, there are terminal blocks with fuse holder mounted on DIN rail: Phoenix contact, Weidmueller, ....many others. Keep in mind that wire cross section determines the fuse, 1A is for very tiny wire I guess you don't have it in your project.

Comment: @MarkoBuršičcI I think i will go with using a fuse holder for now. And also what do you mean by the wire cross-section determines the fuse ?? Can't i just use a 1 amp rated fuse to cut out 1 amp regardless of the cable cross-section ? Please elaborate. Thanks